# Wordpress loop show limit posts

Tags: wordpress

This is the basic loop

`<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

I want to show 20 posts on the search results page. I know we can change the value on admin panel options but it will change all i.e. index page and archive page etc. I need to have them differently.

Answer (score 12):

Great reference:  http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Just before you call the while statement, you need to query the posts.  So:

```
  <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20'); ?>

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Do stuff... -->
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

EDIT:  Sorry about the pagination, try this:

```
    <?php 
        global $query_string;
        query_posts ('posts_per_page=20');
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
    <!-- Do stuff -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- pagination links go here -->

    <? endif; ?>
```

Comment: The codex for query_posts clearly states that pagination will no longer work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination (still looking for a solution myself)

Comment: Correction: it only works on Page templates. In the normal loop you have to use Settings > Reading.

Comment: Not working for me (the list disappears) but @nayeri solution does work (see below).

Answer (score 9):

I find this solution and it works for me.

```
 global $wp_query;
 $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, ['posts_per_page' => 20 ] );
 query_posts( $args );

 if(have_posts()){
   while(have_posts()) {
     the_post();
     //Your code here ...
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of posts per loop through a $wp_query object.
it takes multiple parameters for example:

```
<?php 
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'type of post goes here');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
<!-- DO stuff here-->
?>
```

More on wp_query object  [here->](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'paged' => $paged Pagination would work!

```
<?php 
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
<!-- DO stuff here-->
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers with new query inside template will not work correctly with custom post types.

But [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Removing_query_posts_from_the_main_loop) offers to hook on any query, check is it main query, and modify it before execution. That can be done inside template functions:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // do not alter the query on wp-admin pages and only alter it if it's the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    // alter the query for the home and category pages 
    if(is_home()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before you call the if statement, you need to query the posts.

This one works with archive, custom post types etc.

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=12' );

if ( have_posts() ) :
```