# Limit wordpress posts loop to continue onto another page

Tags: wordpress

Theres a site i did that on the home page, i created kind of like a **news** box type
of thing which is what the client wanted...

the posts bit im using to limit the posts on the index page is

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=4');
```

Now, this limits my posts to "4" or whatever number i want etc, when the user clicks on the 
"news" page button, it takes them to a page which has the full posts loop without the
`query_posts('posts_per_page=4');` which essentially shows them all the posts.

Now the problem is that, this person is posting A LOT now and the page now has a bunch of posts one after the other.

Is there a way to limit these to any number (that i choose) and show the rest of the posts on another page???

So essentially something that says

filter out 20 messages/excerpts for example, BUT after 20 show a "next" page or something like that?

is that possible? Because as it stands now, by years end this ONE page will have hundreds of posts.

ive looked around but not sure exactly what im looking for. This one came close (here on SO) 
[Wordpress loop show limit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875895/wordpress-loop-show-limit-posts)
And although its similar, i need a way to limit the posts on the page AND continue them on another page so that one page doesnt hold ALL the posts.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homepage is controlled by index.php or a template file used by a page which you can set up to be your homepage at Settings > Reading.

You must check your index.php file or the template file used the page from the homepage.

If your queries in the code are not including any "posts per page" arguments, you can control this numbers from Settings > Reading.

There is also a plugin which can help you:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/

Now, clicking on news page, you must check if that is a page or a category listing?

If it's a page, then it is handled by page.php or an attached/used template for it. Again, the code is important, how the queries are written. It it's a category listing, then the category.php is handling that page.

Pay attention for the template files are using each every page/post and learn this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen

In the settings you can set a default max limit of how many posts per page.