# Display number of posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i have the following line code in a wordpress theme and i want to display only 4 or 5 posts. What i have to add?

```
 <div class="mvp-feat1-list-head-wrap left relative">
                            <ul class="mvp-feat1-list-buts left relative">
                                <li class="mvp-feat-col-tab"><a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col1"><span class="mvp-feat1-list-but"><?php esc_html_e( 'Latest', 'zox-news' ); ?></span></a></li>
                                <?php query_posts(array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'post-format-video' )) )); if (have_posts()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col2"><span class="mvp-feat1-list-but"><?php esc_html_e( 'Videos', 'zox-news' ); ?></span></a></li>
                                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                <?php query_posts(array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'post-format-gallery' )) )); if (have_posts()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col3"><span class="mvp-feat1-list-but"><?php esc_html_e( 'Galleries', 'zox-news' ); ?></span></a></li>
                                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Browse here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875895/wordpress-loop-show-limit-posts

Answer (score 2):

Pass `'posts_per_page' => 2` in array [more detailed here explanation is here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)

```
<div class="mvp-feat1-list-head-wrap left relative">
    <ul class="mvp-feat1-list-buts left relative">
    <li class="mvp-feat-col-tab">
        <a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col1"><span class="mvp-feat1-list-but"><?php esc_html_e( 'Latest', 'zox-news' ); ?></span></a>
    </li>
    <?php 
    query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 5,'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'post-format-video' )) )); 
    if (have_posts()) : ?><li><a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col2"><span class="mvp-feat1-list-but"><?php esc_html_e( 'Videos', 'zox-news' ); ?></span></a></li>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 5,'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_format', 'field'=> 'slug', 'terms' => 'post-format-gallery' )) )); if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#mvp-feat-tab-col3">
                <span class="mvp-feat1-list-but">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Galleries', 'zox-news' ); ?>
                    </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```