# PHP The Loop and For Loop

Tags: php

I would have thought this would be straight forward but my understanding of The Loop is limited.

I have about 6 blog posts on my WordPress site. However, I only want to display only 2 of them on the main page.

I thought The Loop nested inside of a For Loop would have worked but to no avail.

Below is my code, that is not working. It loops through 6 posts 3 times. So it is outputting 18 posts instead of the intended 2.

```
<?php

      for($x = 0; $x<=2; $x++) {
      while(have_posts()) {

        the_post(); ?>

      <h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta text-muted">
          <?php the_time('F Y'); ?> by  <a href="#"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> in <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></a>
        </p>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        <?php 

       }} ?>
```

Comment: the for loop runs. then you while loop will run for each have_post. Then you do the same thing twice more.

Comment: Yes... I know. How do I fix it?

Comment: surely there is a WordPress way to only retrieve 2 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress loop show limit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875895/wordpress-loop-show-limit-posts)